# Add button "Add to cart" into widget

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have related products on my website. But there is no option for adding "Add to cart" button.

This is code:

```
  <aside class="widget widget-upsell">

    <h3 class="widget-title shop-sidebar">
      <?php _e( 'You may also like&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
      <div class="is-divider small"></div>
    </h3>

    <!-- Upsell List style -->
    <ul class="product_list_widget">
    <?php foreach ( $upsells as $upsell ) : ?>

      <?php
          $post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );

          setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

          wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-small' ); ?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul><!-- row -->
  </aside>
```

Can somebody help me to add this button?

Answer (score 0):

If think it's because of the `'product-small'` arguments of `wc_get_template_part();`.

Call the function this way :

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
```

By the way, you can do the setup_postdata easier, with the use of `$post` and `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `endforeach;`. This is necessary to reset the post of the current page.

```
<!-- Upsell List style -->
<ul class="product_list_widget">
    <?php foreach ($upsells as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>

      <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul><!-- row -->
```

Here is the code to get the add to cart button if you want it for another time: (Should work in a form)

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
```